# Junk Mail folder in Outlook 2016 with MS Office 365 Pro Plus

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, spam-prevention

For my corporate email, I use Outlook 2016 version 1705 on Windows 10 - This is the Outlook I download using the subscription of Office 365 Pro Plus.

Is there a way to block email ids or domains so that their mail never reaches you - i.e. it doesn't even go to the Junk Folder.

Also, I do not want a junk folder - I want to either block emails or have them come to the mailbox.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can't prevent that in your local PC. That depends on settings at the email **server**. If it's corporate, talk to your IT department. If personal like GMail, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule in Outlook that will delete unwanted messages automatically:
"Apply this rule on messages I receive" -> "from people or public group" (or "with specific words in the sender's address" if you you want a domain) -> "delete it".

Comment: Any spam mails which come in the night when my Outlook is not running goes to the Junk Folder before the rule can see it.

Comment: This is how Outlook works. If you need server-side processing, you need to create a transport rule on Office 365 Exchange Server.